# Kotlin probleme with generating Kdoc

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kdoc

Hi i am having trouble with Kdoc so i followed this : https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/08/dokka-preview-based-on-kotlin-1-4-0-rc/
I was able to add the plugins in the gradle base project, then with the command `./gradlew dokkaHtml` on the terminal i was able to generate the doc. Here is the outcome : [image]

It work pretty well but i don't understand with i don't have all the class listed under docs as it is in the link i followed. And what do i have to add to have this nice presentation ?

I also having an other problem, i have a class with a companion object but this one is not displayed, i have been searching but i couldn't find anything on how to display a companion object in Kdoc, if anyone could help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that i was opening the idem.html file with the browser so the Js doesn't apply.
I set put mamp to create a local server cos i'am on mac, use wamp on windows. To set it up, download it on https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/ then put your documentation file on htdocs repository mine is on the MAMP repo ... then just go to your web browser and type : Localhost:8888:Yourdocname then all the js will be apply, so i had both my companion object and the table of content.